# Two LINQ statements that should return the same thing are not

Tags: c#, linq

This is for LINQ to SQL

Here is the first query:

```
            var rc = from site in customer.OrganizationSites
                 from gt in site.GeneralTransactions
                 where (gt.DealPackage.PackageTransactionDetail.StartDate <= periodStart
                 && gt.DealPackage.PackageTransactionDetail.EndDate >= periodEnd)
                 || (gt.DealPackage.PackageTransactionDetail.StartDate >= periodStart
                 && gt.DealPackage.PackageTransactionDetail.EndDate <= periodEnd)
                 && gt.IsVerified.HasValue
                 && gt.IsVerified.Value
                 && (!gt.Invoices.Any()
                 || !gt.Invoices.Any(i => i.StartDate >= periodStart && i.EndDate <= periodEnd))
                 select gt;
```

Here is the second:

```
var rc = from site in customer.OrganizationSites
     from gt in site.GeneralTransactions
     where (gt.DealPackage.PackageTransactionDetail.StartDate <= periodStart
     && gt.DealPackage.PackageTransactionDetail.EndDate >= periodEnd)
     || (gt.DealPackage.PackageTransactionDetail.StartDate >= periodStart
     && gt.DealPackage.PackageTransactionDetail.EndDate <= periodEnd)
     && gt.IsVerified.HasValue
     && gt.IsVerified.Value
     select gt;

rc = from gt in rc
     where !gt.Invoices.Any()
     || !gt.Invoices.Any(i => i.StartDate >= periodStart && i.EndDate <= periodEnd)
     select gt;
```

The second one simply does the first one in two steps but the second one returns what I'm actually looking for (in this case, nothing), I think I'm making an error somewhere but can't see where. I'd greatly appreciate if anyone could point out why.

Comment: Is this LINQ to Objects? LINQ to SQL? EF? Something else? If it's something that ends up being converted to SQL, have you looked at the generated SQL in each case? Have you tried removing parts of the queries to simplify them?

Comment: You have more parentheses in the first query around the first filters... have you tried making the two *exactly* the same? (I don't want to start reasoning about the precedence here...)

Comment: LINQ to SQL. I haven't actually looked at what query it generates. This is more to verify that the LINQ statement is actually the same.

Comment: I just wrapped the second query's second part with the same parentheses and it still returned what I was expecting.

Comment: Right, so I suggest you: 1) edit your question to show that it happens when they're really the same; 2) reduce the complexity of the queries as far as possible - you're aiming for a *minimal* example; 3) log the SQL and post both queries.

Comment: Edited now. Do the two LINQ statements look the same to you though?

Comment: @VincentLee You need to provide the relevant information *before* you can get an answer.  You can't get an answer and *then* provide the relevant information needed to get an answer.  Well, at least if you want a *good* answer.

Comment: @Servy I'd like to know if the two are syntactically identical at this point. Obviously the queries resulting from both statements are different otherwise the results wouldn't be different.

Comment: No, they are not. The reason is explained in @hvd answer.

Comment: @VincentLee Why are you so strongly opposed to providing the relevant information to properly diagnose your problem?

Comment: @Servy I'm not, just trying to do too many things at once! Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query has a top-level `||`. Combining `a || b` and `c` should give `(a || b) && c`, but you're making it `a || b && c`, meaning `a || (b && c)`.

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed that.